# I'm trying to insert tuples into a table A (from table B) if the primary key of the table B tuple doesn't exist in tuple A

Tags: postgresql, insert

Here is what I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO Tenants (LeaseStartDate, LeaseExpirationDate, Rent, LeaseTenantSSN, RentOverdue)
SELECT CURRENT_DATE, NULL, NewRentPayments.Rent, NewRentPayments.LeaseTenantSSN, FALSE from NewRentPayments
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Tenants, NewRentPayments WHERE NewRentPayments.HouseID = Tenants.HouseID AND 
NewRentPayments.ApartmentNumber = Tenants.ApartmentNumber)
```

So, HouseID and ApartmentNumber together make up the primary key. If there is a tuple in table B (NewRentPayments) that doesn't exist in table A (Tenants) based on the primary key, then it needs to be inserted into Tenants.

The problem is, when I run my query, it doesn't insert anything (I know for a fact there should be 1 tuple inserted). I'm at a loss, because it looks like it should work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subquery was not correlated - It was just a non-correlated join query.

As per description of your problem, you don't need this join.

Try this:

```
insert into Tenants (LeaseStartDate, LeaseExpirationDate, Rent, LeaseTenantSSN, RentOverdue)
select current_date, null, p.Rent, p.LeaseTenantSSN, FALSE
from NewRentPayments p
where not exists (
        select *
        from Tenants t
        where p.HouseID = t.HouseID
            and p.ApartmentNumber = t.ApartmentNumber
        )
```

Comment: Yours works, but what exactly is the difference (besides cleaning up some of the notation?) Thanks.

Comment: I do not have NewRentPayments inside the subquery, which was hindering the correlation

Comment: Ohh, well, at least I was close. Thanks again.